# Low oil price and impact

Tags: productivity, oil

Today I read  an artcicle about the falling oil price (maybe it'll go under 30$ per barel the next days). Why is this a bad news? Lower oil price can give an advantage for a higher productivity.

Comment: Why do you think it is bad news? Without us having seen the article this is difficult to guess. Perhaps it was in the Oil Producer's Weekly magazine.

Comment: As Giskard pointed out it’s not bad news and most economists know it. In fact it’s an example of positive supply shock in some textbooks as a lot of industry still runs on oil... of course it’s a bad news for oil producers and people who invested heavily in oil on commodity markets, but overall people will benefit

Comment: @1muflon1 I did not point out that falling oil prices are not bad news. I was asking for a source/more details.

Comment: @Giskard Bloomberg article....https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-03-08/oil-in-freefall-after-saudis-slash-prices-in-all-out-crude-war?srnd=premium-europe

Comment: The article seems to be clear on whom this is good for and whom this is bad for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessarily bad news.

Simply put, if you're willing to buy product x (bread, car, house, ect.) then falling prices are good news for buyers, but bad news for the sellers. The same logic applies for oil. If you are a buyer, you are optimistic about falling prices, however being a seller would make you loose money and/or postpone new investments.